# Output of relevant commands

Tags: feature-request

There are many instances when the community requests the asker to run certain commands and post the output. They usually ask them to *edit* their answer and just dump the output of the requested commands.

This method works well when the command produces a one line output. But what if it's something like `dmesg` or `lshw`. Often, the output of a command is quite long. This makes the question quite unaesthetic, and sometimes even unreadable.

One way to avoid having the command outputs take up the whole page is to add an expandable item. Something like a text that says

▶ Output of `dmesg`

that when clicked, expands and shows the output in a box with scroll bars.

Of course, if this becomes a feature, the site can suggest running relevant commands based on question tags right when the question is being created. That way more time can be saved.

Comment: Brilliant. To be honest, If I run into a post of 2m2 of terminal output, I immediately skip because of the ugly reading and the lack of overview.

Comment: I support this request +1

Comment: While useful, long dumps should be pastebinned, IMO